# Can I combine two heat-maps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I have two heat-maps and related point data layers, one of correspondent sender addresses, the other of recipient addresses. I wish to identify clusters -- hotspots -- of sender and receiver addresses.

In QGIS, can I create a heat-map from the two point layers to show densities (the Heat-map Plugin only accepts one vector input layer)? Or can I combine the two heat-map rasters to show the coincidences of data?

(QGIS 2.12+)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be easily achieved with 'Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Vector Layers'.  Does what it says in the tin and merges you two point layers to a single shape file.  You can happily add a heatmap style or  create a heatmap layer then depending which version you're using.

Answer (score 10):

[Knightshound](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/73835/knightshound)'s answer is correct. Another option, if you don't want to create yet another file and keep ti always updated, is to use Virtual Layers. I'm not sure if Virtual Layers is available in QGIS 2.12 though.

- Click add Virtual Layer button
- Enter the following SQL query

```sql
select geometry from senders
union all
select geometry from receivers
```

- Click OK

[image]

Now you will have a brand new layer called virtual_layer, that you can use to create the joined heatmap.

[image]

Note that the virtual layer will be updated once any of the to layer are edited. Which is nice.

Comment: Nice work using virtual layers. Pretty much perfect for this.  Maybe we should rename them to Query layers in 3.0

Comment: That is a good idea. Seems a more obvious name for what it does.

Comment: QGIS 2.14.1 on Ubuntu generates an error with this solution. <br/>   The Layer is not valid: The layer ?query=select%20geometry%20from%20sender%0Aunion%20all%0Aselect%20geometry%20from%20receiver is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map  <br/>  Not tried it in other versions yet. Merge Vector Layers does do what I want.

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct layers' names?

Comment: I am using this in QGIS 2.14.5 without problems and with multiple layers.

Comment: Yes, using correct layer names (I have used 'sender' and 'receiver', as in the error message).

Comment: What is your layers' data format? SHP?

Comment: Correct, both input layers are SHP point layers, both to same CRS. One layer has significantly more entries than the other, and there will be identical entries in the ID columns of both attribute tables.

Comment: No idea of what could be wrong. Maybe it's a bug that was fixed already in qgis 2.14.5

Comment: Same error in QGIS 2.16.1 in Ubuntu 14.04 (both as 64-bit)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: according to https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Enhancement-Proposals/issues/44 virtual layers were added to 2.14

Comment: OK, this can be done (QGIS 2.14.1, Ubuntu 16.04), but not in the way I think you mean.  
  
Create a new SpatiaLite layer  
Use DB Manager to import the two vector point layers (I have issues creating Spatial Indexes, so I import the layer, then create the Spatial Indexes as separate processes)  
Load the two layers from the SpatiaLite db  
Using DB Manager/SQL Window, create the virtual layer (QueryLayer) using the query:  
select * from sender  
union all  
select * from receiver  
  
How do I provide sample data? (Having trouble formatting this message correctly.)

Comment: Dropbox, drive or WeTransfer.

Comment: Virtual layers work for all QGIS layers, no need to import into other formats.