# How do I combine heatmaps in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, heat-map

I'm trying to create a view of two heatmaps in the same time with QGIS.  I tried following the suggestion on this thread:
[Can I combine two heat-maps in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215041/can-i-combine-two-heat-maps-in-qgis)
But it didn't work.  The virtual layer only showed one of the heatmaps and not the other, as in this screenshot.  Is there another workaround for this? [image]

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, everything is perfect - what do you think does not work? A heatmap can't show twice. With the virtual layer, you combined all points from rabbits layer and coyote layer. From this combined points you create a heatmap. If that makes sense is another question. If you want to have two separate heatmaps, create them as raster layers as described here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381393/88814

Comment: What you could do: creat a separate heatmap for each points layer. On the layer that is on the top, open Layer Rendering (at the very bottom), set Blending mode to multiply, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBKG5.png. So the pixels of the bottom layer will be "added" (multiplied) to the top layer, thus you will see a kind of an overlay of both heatmaps. Again: if that makes sense is another question.